# iPhone toggleEdit - disable delete?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When I execute toggleEdit, a red button with a white line in the middle shows up on the left (to enable delete) and a blue button with a white arrow shows up on the right of each cell in my UITable:

```
 -(IBAction)toggleEdit:(id)sender {
     [self.table setEditing:!self.table.editing animated:YES];
 }
```

The blue button on the right shows up because for each cell I have:

```
 cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

Is it possible when executing toggleEdit to not show the red button on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In your:

```
 - (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 }
```

just return anything other than UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete for items that are can't be deleted.

Comment: Sweet!  I added the return as UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone and that did the trick.  Thanks!